# How to include latitude and longitude from geopoint using rxjs/Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I assume the Observeable maps a line from the firestore db document fields. How ever the geopoint field is not displayed. The following code shows that the latitude and longitude are extracted properly but i do not know how to get them to appear on the web page.

The Item model code:

```
id?: string;  
lname?: string;
cname?: string;
authid?: string;
epc?: string;
latitude?: string;
longitude?: string;
```

The service component code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, 
     AngularFirestoreCollection, 
     AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from'rxjs/Observable';
import { Item } from '../models/Item';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    woodyplantsCollection: 
    AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
    woodyplants: Observable<Item[]>;
    itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
        this.woodyplantsCollection = 
        this.afs.collection('woodyplants', ref=> 
        ref.orderBy('lname', 'asc').limit(3));         
        this.woodyplants =        
        this.woodyplanttsCollection.
        snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
            return changes.map(a => {     
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;      
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;   
            data.latitude = a.payload.doc.data().geopoint.latitude.toString();
            data.longitude = a.payload.doc.data().geopoint.longitude.toString();
            console.log("Latitude:",data.latitude);
            console.log("Longitude:", data.longitude);
            return data;     
            });
        });
```

Comment: when is rosey coming back online?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you can add key value pairs that match your model.

```
this.woodyplants = this.woodyplanttsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
     return changes.map(a => {       
       const id = a.payload.doc.id;  
       const latitude = a.payload.doc.data().geopoint.latitude.toString();
       const longitude = a.payload.doc.data().geopoint.longitude.toString();

       return {id:id,latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude};    
   });
});
```